# What is the purpose of `last` argument in TCL 8.4 string totitle command?

Tags: arguments, tcl

[TCL 8.4 doc](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/string.html#M34:%7E:text=the%20index%20method.-,string%20totitle%20string%20%3Ffirst%3F%20%3Flast%3F,-Returns%20a%20value) defines the command : `string totitle string ?first? ?last?`
When is the ?last? argument ever relevant?

I have tried the command on multi-word strings assuming that it will auto-capitalize characters after a space character if its in range of the [first, last] indices, but it does not. I don't see a practical reason why this argument exists otherwise.

Comment: Try: `string totitle HELLO 0 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your understanding of this command is incorrect.  Only the first character will be capitalized, all others will be lowercase.

However, let say you have a string that is has a proper name in it
(eg. "cHAPter one: Frank's first flight"), and you do not want the person's name to be made lowercase.  In my contrived example below, I know there is a colon before the person's name, and I can use that to stop 'totitle' from changing characters past the colon.

Example:

```
set myString "cHAPter one: Frank's first flight"
    
set index [string first \: $myString]
    
puts [string totitle $myString 0 end]
    
# results in: Chapter one: frank's first flight
# Whereas:

puts [string totitle $myString 0 $index]
    
# results in: Chapter one: Frank's first flight
```